# Flutter: flutter_tex TeXView not working. Shows "ImeThread is not enabled"

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

**TeXView can't show any text. It shows ImeThread is not enabled.**

I want to show mathematical equations in my app. So, I am using [flutter_tex](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_tex) to show mathematical equations. It's working fine in previous version of [flutter_tex](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_tex) package. But current version can't show any text or equations.

**Console shows**:

```
D/Surface ( 5430): Surface::setBufferCount(this=0x8ae13f00,bufferCount=4)
D/WebView ( 5430): loadUrl(extra headers)=http://localhost:5353/packages/flutter_tex/src/tex_libs/katex/index.html?teXViewServerPort=5353
I/cr_Ime  ( 5430): ImeThread is not enabled.
```

**My code:**

```
TeXView(
    renderingEngine: RenderingEngine.Katex,
    children: [
      TeXViewChild(
          id: "child_1",
          title: r"<h3>Quadratic Equation</h3>",
          body: r"""<p>
                       When \(a \ne 0 \), there are two solutions to \(ax^2 + bx + c = 0\) and they are
                       $$x = {-b \pm \sqrt{b^2-4ac} \over 2a}.$$</p>""",
          decoration: TeXViewDecoration(
              style: TeXViewStyle(
                backgroundColor: Colors.green,
                contentColor: Colors.white,
              ),
              titleStyle: TeXViewStyle(
                textAlign: TeXViewTextAlign.Center,
                backgroundColor: Colors.red,
                contentColor: Colors.white,
              ),
              bodyStyle: TeXViewStyle.fromCSS(
                  "color:white;background-color:light-green")))
    ],
    style: TeXViewStyle(
      elevation: 10,
      border: TeXViewBorder(
          all: TeXViewBorderDecoration(
              borderColor: Colors.blue,
              borderStyle: TeXViewBorderStyle.Solid,
              borderWidth: 5)),
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
    ),
    loadingWidget: Center(
      child: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
          CircularProgressIndicator(),
          Text("Rendering with ")
        ],
      ),
    ),
    onTap: (childID) {
      print("TeXView $childID is tapped.");
    }),
```

Please help me if you know why this problem occur and how to solve it.

**Thanks**

Comment: Have you solved your problem? If not please consider the latest version of flutter_tex.

Comment: thanks for comment. this issue is closed now. I had created an issue and now solved it. see here https://github.com/shah-xad/flutter_tex/issues/41